# How to perform a MySQL search that ignores punctuation in table data

Tags: mysql, punctuation

I have a multiple tables that contain large amounts of text.
The text has a lot of punctuation in it.

```
MY_TABLE
|ID|       TEXT        |
------------------------
|1 |Dr. John Smith, FNP|
```

If I search:

```
SELECT * FROM `MY_TABLE` WHERE `TEXT` LIKE '%Dr. John Smith, FNP%'
```

Row 1 is returned.

If I search:

```
SELECT * FROM `MY_TABLE` WHERE `TEXT` LIKE '%Dr John Smith FNP%'
```

0 Rows are returned.

How can I perform a search that ignores the punctuation that is **in the data**?

I have to search many tables at once, and each table contains 10's of thousands of rows, all with paragraphs of text.

So - speed will be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

As  first option you could try replacing  the not desidered  chars

```
    SELECT * FROM `MY_TABLE` 
    WHERE REPLACE(REPLACE( `TEXT`, ',',''),'.','') 
        LIKE '%Dr John Smith FNP%'
```

or using multiple wildchar

```
SELECT 'OK'  FROM  dual WHERE 'Dr. John Smith, FNP' LIKE '%Dr%John%Smith%FNP%'
```

.

```
SELECT * FROM  `MY_TABLE`  WHERE 'Dr. John Smith, FNP' LIKE '%Dr%John%Smith%FNP%'
```

and last you can use REGEX_REPLACE

```
WHERE REGEXP_REPLACE('[,.]+', '', `TEXT`) LIKE '%Dr John Smith FNP%';
```

Answer (score 0):

You could remove punctuation from the `TEXT` column in a concise way using `REGEXP_REPLACE` on MySQL 8+:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE REGEXP_REPLACE('[,.;:]+', '', TEXT) LIKE '%Dr John Smith FNP%';
```

This is a fairly clean approach, because if it turns out that you need to remove additional punctuation characters, you need only add them to the character class of the regex pattern.

Comment: This seems like a good solution - but is it reasonable to worry about the time this will take on very large text columns, and many rows, and multiple tables?

Comment: @Stnfordly Your performance concerns are valid, and in that case consider using the other answer (though _either_ solution won't generally be very fast).